# Should I use props or states in order to pass data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching an array of items (call'em movies) from an API. Every movie has several details (title, director, cast, synopsis etc)

Here's a diagram of my structure:

[image: components structure]

Here is the MoviesList component :

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      movies: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3335/movies')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
      }).then((movies) => {
        this.setState({ movies });
      }).catch(function(ex) {
        console.log('parsing failed', ex)
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="movies">
        <Movie movies={this.state.movies}></Movie>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And here is the movie:

```
render() {

    const movielist = this.props.movies.map((movie) =>
        <li>{movie.title}</li>
    );

    return (
      <ul className="movie">
        { movielist }
      </ul>
    );

}
```

My questions:

1. Should I use state or props to pass the data down from Movielist to Movie
2. Since there's no "for" templating, how do I make it so I am not creating a list inside `Movie` but I am instead looping the entire `Movie` component inside `Movielist` ?

For example, I would like to achieve the following inside MovieList:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="movies">
        <Movie for movie in movies></Movie>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Why not let the movielist do the mapping in it's render procedure, and movie just shows 1 single movie? The details send to movie should/would be through props, the movielist can have the state, but you could also add some MovieStore and let that define the state for movielist

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do - (not familiar with stores yet, taking it one step at a time) - do you mind adding an answer with the alternative implementation?

Comment: if you use your component such way why dont't name them as `smart` and `dumb` components? So your `MoviesList` is actually a `Container` (_should fetch data and pass via props to component_) and the `movie` is a `Component` (_should only show received data_). In that case maybe better to rename `movie` to `DumbMovieList` :) So in general it's good approach in your expample. Why do you need `for in`? For me `const movielist = this.props.movies.map` is a good way! Or something wrong with it?

Comment: @OlegPro the `for in` part was pseudocode to show what I wanted to achieve. (sidenote: I do find the mapping part hard to read, it doesn't come natural to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`render()` of `MovieList` :**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="movies">
        {
          this.state.movies
          ? <ul>
              {this.state.movies.map((movie, index) => <Movie title={movie.title} key={index}/>)}
            </ul>
          : null
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

---

**`render()` of `Movie` :**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <li className="movie">{this.props.title}</li>
    );
  }
```

Comment: how do you pass the entire movie item and not just the title?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos Just use `<Movie {...movie} />` ;)

Comment: as @Icepickle said,  you can do it implicitly: `<Movie {...movie} />` or explicitly: `<Movie title={movie.title}  />` or as an object `movieData`: `<Movie movieData={movie} />`. Now inside `Movie` you can access `this.props.movieData.title`.

Comment: is there any way we can make the MovieList render code a bit more readable? any more "this is a loop" straightforward way or writing this? (I miss templates..)

Comment: @free-soul last thing: I get the `warning.js:36 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop`

Comment: React is just JavaScript, it doesn't has any in-built templates. You can of course move the `<ul>{this.state.movies.map((movie) => <Movie title={movie.title}/>)}</ul>` to a separate function and call it inside `MovieList`'s `render()`.

Comment: add a unique key prop to each Movie element: `{this.state.movies.map((movie, index) => <Movie key={index} title={movie.title}/>)}`. Adding a unique key prop for an array of elements is enforced by React to help the diffing algorithm. Updated the answer.

Comment: @free-soul I am facing an issue; when trying to create a route /movie/:id and trigger `Movieslist` but with only 1 Movie.. this doesn't fit this implementation. What should be the best practice for that?

Answer (score 1):

i props/state - I think what you're doing is fine; passing your outer component's (*MoviesList*) state down to its child as a prop (you wouldn't set the outer component's own properties with the result of the api call).

ii You can map over the movies in your outer component, for example:

```
    renderMovie(movie) {
        return (
          <Movie movie={movie} /> 
        ); 
    }

    render() 
    { 
      return ( 
        <div className="movies">
          <ul>
            { this.state.movies.map(this.renderMovie) } 
          </ul>
        </div>
      ); 
    }
```

Comment: what's "renderMovie" ?

Comment: Sorry George, just a stub where you'd implement your movie rendering; I'll update the answer.

Comment: Mark, imagine that the movie not only has a name but also many other properties I want to display - therefore I wouldn't like to have to do all that in the MoviesList but just pass everything to Movie and let it handle the rendering..

Comment: Then the renderMovie method could render the Movie component, but whereas in your original, Movie accepted a list of movies as a prop, the Movie component would now just take a single instance of a movie and render that? (I've updated the answer.)

Comment: That matches the pluralisation of your components (ie Movie should just be concerned with rendering one instance of a movie.)

Comment: You'll have to create it it similarly to the one I provided; alternatively just inline the rendering as in the map section.

Comment: here it should be `{ this.state.movies.map(this.renderMovie) } `!

Comment: thank you @MarkWilliams , I upvoted your answer by selected the (later posted) one from free-soul as he included the movie detail part.. I hope that's ok